# Can WSO2 API Manager send JMS messages to TIBCO EMS Server directly (No ESB in between)? How?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, tibco-ems

I'm trying to understand if and how is possible to send a JMS message to TIBCO EMS Server using WSO2 API Manager **without** using the WSO2 ESB in between.

The Pattern 1 of this article: http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/10/article-how-to-enable-wso2-api-manager-to-work-as-a-jms-producer/ does something similar but for Apache ActiveMQ.

Is this possible? Any hint? Article?

Thanks in advance,

Gianfranco

Answer (score 0):

EMS is a JMS provider like ActiveMQ.

The [feature list](http://wso2.com/api-management/features/) mention : Maps between HTTP(s) and other protocols, such as **JMS** or writing to file systems.

You can ix the article you already have with JMS examples from the sample folder on a typical EMS installation.

I think the code will be mostly the same... but your are going to depend on jar provided inside the EMS installation.

Comment: This was exactly the "JMS Server agnostic" behavior I was expecting from API Manager.

Comment: Unfortunately, even copying the TIBCO EMS Server client libraries in the Carbon classpath [AM_HOME]/repository/components/lib and uncommenting the <transportSender name="jms" section in the [AM_HOME]/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml didn't help.

At startup AM throws:
`[...] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender cannot be found by axis2_1.6.1.wso2v16`

I sort of made it work with a jar from ESB but don't like this so for now I use EMS between AM and Tibco EMS.

So, still missing a clear way how to make AM work directly with TIBCO EMS Server.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I was facing exactly the same issue. And I sort of fixed doing roughly the same. But as I said I don't like it so I sticked to using ESB (which I don't like 100% but it's "cleaner").
Strange I didn't find that issue page, I made so many searches in internet... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instructions here to configure the APIM[1] axis2.xml file.
As for placing the jars you need to do the following:

1. In the APIM_HOME/lib/endorsed folder delete the geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.0.wso2v1.jar
2. Add the jms-2.0.jar to the APIM_HOME/lib/endorsed folder
3. Add the tibjms.jar in the APIM_HOME/repository/components/libs folder.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/Ei620/Configure+with+Tibco+EMS